# Create right Stream API with java

Tags: java, api, for-loop, lambda, stream

I have next code and I want create Stream API for this fragment:

```
for (Task task : deletedTasks) {
    if (!Objects.isNull(task.getUser())) {
        kafkaSenderTaskProducer.sendAutoRejectedTasksEvent(task.getId(), task.getUser().getId());
    } else {
        kafkaSenderTaskProducer.sendDeletedEvent(task);
    }
}
```

For second else condition I have code, but I don`t know how to type code for first condition

```
deletedTasks.stream()
            .filter(task -> Objects.isNull(task.getUser()))
            .forEach(kafkaSenderTaskProducer::sendDeletedEvent);
```

Can u give me some advice for create Stream API for first condition

Comment: `.forEach(task -> if (...) { ... } else { ... })`. There's no advantage of streams here.

Comment: BTW: `Objects.isNull` is only really meant to be used as a method reference (see [API note](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#isNull(java.lang.Object))). Use `task.getUser() == null` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use stream or filter here. As simple forEach will work for you. Unnecessary use of stream in the code will have performance issue. You can do it as below:

```
deletedTasks.forEach(task -> {
    if(task.getUser() == null) {
       kafkaSenderTaskProducer.sendDeletedEvent(task);
    } else {
       kafkaSenderTaskProducer.sendAutoRejectedTasksEvent(task.getId(), task.getUser().getId());
    }
})
```